# Sum of series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^{k^2}}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am looking at this sum:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^{(k^2)}}{k!}$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Why this problem is interesting for you? And what did you tried in order to solve it? I you want to get help from other members, you should try to add as more context as possible to your question, in order to help them help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get to choose $a$ I choose $1$ and the sum is $e$.

For $a \gt 1$ the sum diverges.

For $0 \lt a \lt 1$ it will converge quickly but I suspect has no easy answer.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%200.5%5E(k%5E2)%2Fk!%20from%201%20to%20infinity) says that for $a=\frac 12$ the sum is about $0.531576$ but does not give a closed form.

Comment: This is a special function, theta or something.